# NaN date issue with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using the [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) library.

I have replicated my problem in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xX8V/).

My problem being when I click on the graph, and take the cursor to another point within the graph, everything works fine.

However if I click, and drag the cursor all the way to the end of the graph (and click) when it is the furthest you can take it, the date value retrieved is equal to 'NaN/NaN/NaN NaN:NaN'.

I thought my code would handle this exception on the line -

```
if (event.min != null || event.max != null) {
```

in that if either `event.min` or `event.max` are undefined i.e. null, then use either `originalFrom` or `originalUntil` respectively.

For some reason I am not entering the `else`-

```
else {
        // this is where the values would be reset to the original 
        // values if either event.min or event.max are undefined  

        $("#t1").val(originalFrom);
        $("#t2").val(originalUntil);
     }
```

However this is not working, I tried changing the aforementioned line to -

```
if (event.min != undefined|| event.max != undefined) {
```

And also tried -

```
if (event.min != NaN || event.max != NaN) {
```

However both came back with the same incorrect NaN value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe try `if (event.min != null && event.max != null)`

Answer (score 2):

To check for NaN you could use the [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (isNaN(event.min) || isNaN(event.max)) {
 //code here
}
```

Comment: same issue im afraid :(